# tabula-py unable to read pdf file

Tags: java, python

My code:

```
import tabula
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
file_path = dir_path + '\ALPINE_' + str(20191107) + '.pdf'
print(file_path)
df = tabula.read_pdf('ALPINE_20191107.pdf',multiple_tables=True, pages="all")
```

result:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/lucas/testTabula.py.py', wdir='C:/Users/Admin/Documents/lucas')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-29-a6b390aef3cf>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/lucas/sem título0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Admin/Documents/lucas')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/lucas/sem título0.py", line 12, in <module>
    df = tabula.read_pdf('ALPINE_20191107.pdf',multiple_tables=True, pages="all")

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tabula\io.py", line 332, in read_pdf
    return _extract_from(raw_json, pandas_options)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tabula\io.py", line 664, in _extract_from
    df[c] = pd.to_numeric(df[c], errors="ignore")

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\numeric.py", line 138, in to_numeric
    raise TypeError("arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series")

TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series
```

It's function doesn't seem to work. I could directly type the path to make even simpler, but it didn't work either. It could be a problem with the pdf file, but I already saw  it working in another environment with the same script and the same file.

I already have java set on both possible PATHs ('C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin') as by documentation but it really doesn't matter, the error occurs with or without then set on PATH. I've tried adding jdk as well but didn't solve either.

I notice the error mentioning pandas so maybe it's conflicting with my version (the latest), but i'm not sure.

python is 3.7.4 and java is the latest to this date

Comment: I've encountered the same problem going from a Windows to a Linux (docker) environment -- I haven't found a solution either.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue. I was using the version installed using pip, i.e. tabula-py 2.0.0. I uninstalled the version, and installed from Anaconda using conda install -c conda-forge tabula-py, and current version is tabula-py 1.4.1, which resolved this issue.